# Workflow Content handling

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.1.1 CE.

I've created a multilevel kaleo workflow (i.e. with two levels of approvals), by writing a definition in a xml file (leaveapproval.xml) and loading it to the server. It works fine as I have tested this workflow in Blogs.

So now, I wants to submit the content of the workflow to a web service after completing the second level approval.

How can i handle the content of the workflow?

Is it possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<workflow-definition
        xmlns="urn:liferay.com:liferay-workflow_6.1.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:liferay.com:liferay-workflow_6.1.0 http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-workflow-definition_6_1_0.xsd">
    <name>LEAVE IN ACTION USER ACTION</name>
    <description>A sample multilevel approver can approve a workflow content.</description>
    <version>1</version>

    <state>
        <name>created</name>
        <metadata>
            <![CDATA[
            {"xy":[36,51]}
            ]]>
        </metadata>
        <initial>true</initial>
        <transitions>
            <transition>
                <name>review</name>
                <target>review</target>
                <default>true</default>
            </transition>
        </transitions>
    </state>

    <task>
        <name>review</name>
        <metadata>
            <![CDATA[
            {"xy":[168,36]}
            ]]>
        </metadata>
        <actions>
            <notification>
                <name>Review Notification</name>
                <template>You have a new submission waiting for review in the workflow.</template>
                <template-language>text</template-language>
                <notification-type>email</notification-type>
                <execution-type>onAssignment</execution-type>
            </notification>
            <notification>
                <name>Review Completion Notification</name>
                <template>
                    Your submission has been reviewed and the reviewer has applied the following ${taskComments}.</template>
                <template-language>freemarker</template-language>
                <notification-type>email</notification-type>
                <recipients>
                    <user />
                </recipients>
                <execution-type>onExit</execution-type>
            </notification>
        </actions>
        <assignments>
            <roles>
                <role>
                    <role-type>regular</role-type>
                    <name>Portal Head</name>
                </role>
                <role>
                    <role-type>regular</role-type>
                    <name>Portal Content Reviewer</name>
                </role>
            </roles>
        </assignments>
        <transitions>
            <transition>
                <name>approve</name>
                <target>recommended</target>
            </transition>
            <transition>
                <name>reject</name>
                <target>update</target>
                <default>false</default>
            </transition>
        </transitions>
     </task>

     <task>
        <name>recommended</name>
        <metadata>
            <![CDATA[{"xy":[168,36]}]]>
        </metadata>
        <actions>
            <notification>
                <name>Review Notification</name>
                <template>You have a new submission waiting for your review in the workflow.</template>
                <template-language>text</template-language>
                <notification-type>email</notification-type>
                <execution-type>onAssignment</execution-type>
            </notification>
            <notification>
                <name>Review Completion Notification</name>
                <template>
                    Your submission has been reviewed and the reviewer has applied the following ${taskComments}.</template>
                <template-language>freemarker</template-language>
                <notification-type>email</notification-type>
                <recipients>
                    <user />
                </recipients>
                <execution-type>onExit</execution-type>
            </notification>
        </actions>
        <assignments>
            <user>
                <user-id>13379</user-id>
            </user>
        </assignments>
        <transitions>
            <transition>
                <name>approve</name>
                <target>approved</target>
            </transition>
            <transition>
                <name>reject</name>
                <target>update</target>
                <default>false</default>
            </transition>
        </transitions>
    </task>

    <task>
        <name>update</name>
        <metadata>
            <![CDATA[
            {"transitions":{"resubmit":{"bendpoints":[[303,140]]}},"xy":[328,199]}
            ]]>
        </metadata>
        <actions>
            <action>
                <name>reject</name>
                <script>
                    <![CDATA[
                    Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStatus(
                        Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants.toStatus("denied"),
                        workflowContext);

                    Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStatus(
                        Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants.toStatus("pending"),
                        workflowContext);
                    ]]>
                </script>
                <script-language>javascript</script-language>
                <execution-type>onAssignment</execution-type>
            </action>
            <notification>
                <name>Creator Modification Notification</name>
                <template>Your submission was rejected by a reviewer, please modify and resubmit.</template>
                <template-language>text</template-language>
                <notification-type>email</notification-type>
                <execution-type>onAssignment</execution-type>
            </notification>
        </actions>
        <assignments>
            <user />
        </assignments>
        <transitions>
            <transition>
                <name>resubmit</name>
                <target>review</target>
            </transition>
        </transitions>
    </task>

    <state>
        <name>approved</name>
        <metadata>
            <![CDATA[
                {"xy":[380,51]}
            ]]>
        </metadata>
        <actions>
            <action>
                <name>approve</name>
                <script>
                    <![CDATA[Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStatus      (Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants.toStatus("approved"), workflowContext);]]>

                </script>
                <script-language>javascript</script-language>
                <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
            </action>
        </actions>
    </state>
</workflow-definition>
```

Help me..

Comment: It should be possible, can you include your `leaveapproval.xml`?

Comment: @PrakashK...updated my question with the definition

Comment: Hello... I download and deploy Kaleo Workflow and used it Pradip Bhatt: It provide just 2 state Accept and Reject Now i have to provide same this single Approval mechanism but with three states 1) Accpet 2)Reject 3)Re-Submit Can you please direct me ?

Answer (score 0):

For running anything programmatically on a certain workflow step, you generally just need a `<script>` tag, just like you're doing to update the statuses.

So, in your approved `<state>`, you'd probably want to add another `<action>` tag, this one to handle the web service call (and let the other action remain the way it is).

The language you'd use for the script will depend on what you're comfortable with. I'd use groovy, since it handles plain java code pretty well, and that's what I know.

Here's what it might look like (only including that last `<state>` tag):

```
<state>
    <name>approved</name>
    <metadata>
        <![CDATA[
        {"xy":[380,51]}
        ]]> 
    </metadata>
    <actions>
        <action>
            <name>approve</name>
            <script>
                <![CDATA[
                Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStatus(
                    Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants.toStatus("approved"),
                    workflowContext);
                ]]>
            </script>
            <script-language>javascript</script-language>
            <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
        </action>
        <action>
            <name>submit-web-service</name>
            <script>
                <![CDATA[
                import java.io.*
                import java.net.*

                URL url = new URL(
                    "www.my-web-service.com/api/whatever?theParam=" +
                        ${theRelevantContextVariable});

                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

                // if necessary to read response data:
                // BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                //    new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                // String something = bufferedReader.readLine();
                // etc.
                ]]>
            </script>
            <script-language>groovy</script-language>
            <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
        </action>
    </actions>
</state>
```

You may need a POST request instead, in which case you'd implement the web service call differently. But in any case you'd write the web service code in an action tag. Something like this should work.